# Raspberry Pi 4b HDMI cannot output 4k at 60hz

Tags: pi-4, hdmi, display

I have a raspberry pi 4b (8GB memory) installed in an Argon ONE v2 case (which automatically expand the micro HDMI port to full HDMI port). I installed the official 64bit OS and updated all packages to the latest version at the time of writing. I did not install any other packages or kernel modules.

```
$ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.15.76-v8+ #1597 SMP PREEMPT Fri Nov 4 12:16:41 GMT 2022 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

I enabled the 4k 60hz using `raspi-config` (`2 Display Options -> D6 Composite -> V1 Enable 4Kp60 HDMI`) and confirmed that `hdmi_enable_4kp60=1` is added in the end of the `/boot/config.txt`. I then rebooted the pi.

Before plugging the pi, I confirmed that my cable and TV (Samsung UN55NU800D) supports 4k 60hz by plugging in my 2021 14 inch MacBook Pro (using builtin HDMI port). The TV shows `3840x2160 / 60p`, indicating 4k 60hz is supported.

I then plugged the pi into the TV with the HDMI cable. The TV shows `3840x2160 / 30p`. I opened the builtin `Screen Layout Editor` GUI (`Start Menu -> Preferences -> Screen Configuration`). Right click the `HDMI-1`. Under `Resolution`, `3840x2160` is selected and `30.000Hz` is selected under `Frequency`. There is no option to select 60hz as other available options are all lower than 30Hz.

I dumped the EDID data of the active HDMI connection (shown below). I am not familiar with these, but it seems like 4k 60hz is supported.

```
$ edid-decode /sys/class/drm/card1-HDMI-A-1/edid 
edid-decode (hex):

00 ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 4c 2d 09 0f 00 0e 00 01
01 1c 01 03 80 79 44 78 0a 23 ad a4 54 4d 99 26
0f 47 4a bd ef 80 71 4f 81 c0 81 00 81 80 95 00
a9 c0 b3 00 01 01 04 74 00 30 f2 70 5a 80 b0 58
8a 00 50 1d 74 00 00 1e 02 3a 80 18 71 38 2d 40
58 2c 45 00 50 1d 74 00 00 1e 00 00 00 fd 00 18
78 0f 87 1e 00 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 00 00 00 fc
00 53 41 4d 53 55 4e 47 0a 20 20 20 20 20 01 b9

02 03 4e f0 55 5f 10 1f 04 13 05 14 20 21 22 5d
5e 62 63 64 07 16 03 12 3f 40 29 09 07 07 15 07
50 57 07 01 83 01 00 00 e2 00 4f e3 05 03 01 6e
03 0c 00 20 00 b8 3c 20 00 80 01 02 03 04 e3 06
0d 01 e5 0e 60 61 65 66 e5 01 8b 84 90 01 01 1d
80 d0 72 1c 16 20 10 2c 25 80 50 1d 74 00 00 9e
66 21 56 aa 51 00 1e 30 46 8f 33 00 50 1d 74 00
00 1e 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10

----------------

Block 0, Base EDID:
  EDID Structure Version & Revision: 1.3
  Vendor & Product Identification:
    Manufacturer: SAM
    Model: 3849
    Serial Number: 16780800
    Made in: week 1 of 2018
  Basic Display Parameters & Features:
    Digital display
    Maximum image size: 121 cm x 68 cm
    Gamma: 2.20
    RGB color display
    First detailed timing is the preferred timing
  Color Characteristics:
    Red  : 0.6406, 0.3300
    Green: 0.3007, 0.6005
    Blue : 0.1503, 0.0605
    White: 0.2802, 0.2900
  Established Timings I & II:
    IBM     :   720x400    70.082 Hz   9:5    31.467 kHz  28.320 MHz
    DMT 0x04:   640x480    59.940 Hz   4:3    31.469 kHz  25.175 MHz
    Apple   :   640x480    66.667 Hz   4:3    35.000 kHz  30.240 MHz
    DMT 0x05:   640x480    72.809 Hz   4:3    37.861 kHz  31.500 MHz
    DMT 0x06:   640x480    75.000 Hz   4:3    37.500 kHz  31.500 MHz
    DMT 0x09:   800x600    60.317 Hz   4:3    37.879 kHz  40.000 MHz
    DMT 0x0a:   800x600    72.188 Hz   4:3    48.077 kHz  50.000 MHz
    DMT 0x0b:   800x600    75.000 Hz   4:3    46.875 kHz  49.500 MHz
    Apple   :   832x624    74.551 Hz   4:3    49.726 kHz  57.284 MHz
    DMT 0x10:  1024x768    60.004 Hz   4:3    48.363 kHz  65.000 MHz
    DMT 0x11:  1024x768    70.069 Hz   4:3    56.476 kHz  75.000 MHz
    DMT 0x12:  1024x768    75.029 Hz   4:3    60.023 kHz  78.750 MHz
    DMT 0x24:  1280x1024   75.025 Hz   5:4    79.976 kHz 135.000 MHz
    Apple   :  1152x870    75.062 Hz 192:145  68.681 kHz 100.000 MHz
  Standard Timings:
    DMT 0x15:  1152x864    75.000 Hz   4:3    67.500 kHz 108.000 MHz
    DMT 0x55:  1280x720    60.000 Hz  16:9    45.000 kHz  74.250 MHz
    DMT 0x1c:  1280x800    59.810 Hz  16:10   49.702 kHz  83.500 MHz
    DMT 0x23:  1280x1024   60.020 Hz   5:4    63.981 kHz 108.000 MHz
    DMT 0x2f:  1440x900    59.887 Hz  16:10   55.935 kHz 106.500 MHz
    DMT 0x53:  1600x900    60.000 Hz  16:9    60.000 kHz 108.000 MHz (RB)
    DMT 0x3a:  1680x1050   59.954 Hz  16:10   65.290 kHz 146.250 MHz
  Detailed Timing Descriptors:
    DTD 1:  3840x2160   30.000 Hz  16:9    67.500 kHz 297.000 MHz (1872 mm x 1053 mm)
                 Hfront  176 Hsync  88 Hback 296 Hpol P
                 Vfront    8 Vsync  10 Vback  72 Vpol P
    DTD 2:  1920x1080   60.000 Hz  16:9    67.500 kHz 148.500 MHz (1872 mm x 1053 mm)
                 Hfront   88 Hsync  44 Hback 148 Hpol P
                 Vfront    4 Vsync   5 Vback  36 Vpol P
  Display Range Limits:
    Monitor ranges (GTF): 24-120 Hz V, 15-135 kHz H, max dotclock 300 MHz
    Display Product Name: 'SAMSUNG'
  Extension blocks: 1
Checksum: 0xb9

----------------

Block 1, CTA-861 Extension Block:
  Revision: 3
  Underscans IT Video Formats by default
  Basic audio support
  Supports YCbCr 4:4:4
  Supports YCbCr 4:2:2
  Native detailed modes: 0
  Video Data Block:
    VIC  95:  3840x2160   30.000 Hz  16:9    67.500 kHz 297.000 MHz
    VIC  16:  1920x1080   60.000 Hz  16:9    67.500 kHz 148.500 MHz
    VIC  31:  1920x1080   50.000 Hz  16:9    56.250 kHz 148.500 MHz
    VIC   4:  1280x720    60.000 Hz  16:9    45.000 kHz  74.250 MHz
    VIC  19:  1280x720    50.000 Hz  16:9    37.500 kHz  74.250 MHz
    VIC   5:  1920x1080i  60.000 Hz  16:9    33.750 kHz  74.250 MHz
    VIC  20:  1920x1080i  50.000 Hz  16:9    28.125 kHz  74.250 MHz
    VIC  32:  1920x1080   24.000 Hz  16:9    27.000 kHz  74.250 MHz
    VIC  33:  1920x1080   25.000 Hz  16:9    28.125 kHz  74.250 MHz
    VIC  34:  1920x1080   30.000 Hz  16:9    33.750 kHz  74.250 MHz
    VIC  93:  3840x2160   24.000 Hz  16:9    54.000 kHz 297.000 MHz
    VIC  94:  3840x2160   25.000 Hz  16:9    56.250 kHz 297.000 MHz
    VIC  98:  4096x2160   24.000 Hz 256:135  54.000 kHz 297.000 MHz
    VIC  99:  4096x2160   25.000 Hz 256:135  56.250 kHz 297.000 MHz
    VIC 100:  4096x2160   30.000 Hz 256:135  67.500 kHz 297.000 MHz
    VIC   7:  1440x480i   59.940 Hz  16:9    15.734 kHz  27.000 MHz
    VIC  22:  1440x576i   50.000 Hz  16:9    15.625 kHz  27.000 MHz
    VIC   3:   720x480    59.940 Hz  16:9    31.469 kHz  27.000 MHz
    VIC  18:   720x576    50.000 Hz  16:9    31.250 kHz  27.000 MHz
    VIC  63:  1920x1080  120.000 Hz  16:9   135.000 kHz 297.000 MHz
    VIC  64:  1920x1080  100.000 Hz  16:9   112.500 kHz 297.000 MHz
  Audio Data Block:
    Linear PCM:
      Max channels: 2
      Supported sample rates (kHz): 48 44.1 32
      Supported sample sizes (bits): 24 20 16
    AC-3:
      Max channels: 6
      Supported sample rates (kHz): 48 44.1 32
      Maximum bit rate: 640 kb/s
    Enhanced AC-3 (DD+):
      Max channels: 8
      Supported sample rates (kHz): 48 44.1 32
      Supports Joint Object Coding
  Speaker Allocation Data Block:
    FL/FR - Front Left/Right
  Video Capability Data Block:
    YCbCr quantization: No Data
    RGB quantization: Selectable (via AVI Q)
    PT scan behavior: No Data
    IT scan behavior: Supports both over- and underscan
    CE scan behavior: Supports both over- and underscan
  Colorimetry Data Block:
    xvYCC601
    xvYCC709
  Vendor-Specific Data Block (HDMI), OUI 00-0C-03:
    Source physical address: 2.0.0.0
    Supports_AI
    DC_36bit
    DC_30bit
    DC_Y444
    Maximum TMDS clock: 300 MHz
    Extended HDMI video details:
      HDMI VICs:
        HDMI VIC 1:  3840x2160   30.000 Hz  16:9    67.500 kHz 297.000 MHz
        HDMI VIC 2:  3840x2160   25.000 Hz  16:9    56.250 kHz 297.000 MHz
        HDMI VIC 3:  3840x2160   24.000 Hz  16:9    54.000 kHz 297.000 MHz
        HDMI VIC 4:  4096x2160   24.000 Hz 256:135  54.000 kHz 297.000 MHz
  HDR Static Metadata Data Block:
    Electro optical transfer functions:
      Traditional gamma - SDR luminance range
      SMPTE ST2084
      Hybrid Log-Gamma
    Supported static metadata descriptors:
      Static metadata type 1
  YCbCr 4:2:0 Video Data Block:
    VIC  96:  3840x2160   50.000 Hz  16:9    56.250 kHz 297.000 MHz
    VIC  97:  3840x2160   60.000 Hz  16:9    67.500 kHz 297.000 MHz
    VIC 101:  4096x2160   50.000 Hz 256:135  56.250 kHz 297.000 MHz
    VIC 102:  4096x2160   60.000 Hz 256:135  67.500 kHz 297.000 MHz
  Vendor-Specific Video Data Block (HDR10+), OUI 90-84-8B:
    Application Version: 1
  Detailed Timing Descriptors:
    DTD 3:  1920x1080i  50.000 Hz  16:9    28.125 kHz  74.250 MHz (1872 mm x 1053 mm)
                 Hfront  528 Hsync  44 Hback 148 Hpol P
                 Vfront    2 Vsync   5 Vback  15 Vpol P Vfront +0.5 Odd Field
                 Vfront    2 Vsync   5 Vback  15 Vpol P Vback  +0.5 Even Field
    DTD 4:  1366x768    59.790 Hz 683:384  47.712 kHz  85.500 MHz (1872 mm x 1053 mm)
                 Hfront   70 Hsync 143 Hback 213 Hpol P
                 Vfront    3 Vsync   3 Vback  24 Vpol P
Checksum: 0x10
```

I also dumped the available display options using `xrandr` (shown below)

```
$ xrandr --verbose
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 7680 x 7680
HDMI-1 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (0x48) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1872mm x 1053mm
    Identifier: 0x45
    Timestamp:  1704831
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff004c2d090f000e0001
        011c0103807944780a23ada4544d9926
        0f474abdef80714f81c0810081809500
        a9c0b300010104740030f2705a80b058
        8a00501d7400001e023a801871382d40
        582c4500501d7400001e000000fd0018
        780f871e000a202020202020000000fc
        0053414d53554e470a202020202001b9
        02034ef0555f101f041305142021225d
        5e626364071603123f40290907071507
        5057070183010000e2004fe30503016e
        030c002000b83c20008001020304e306
        0d01e50e60616566e5018b849001011d
        80d0721c1620102c2580501d7400009e
        662156aa51001e30468f3300501d7400
        001e0000000000000000000000000010
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    max bpc: 8 
        range: (8, 12)
    bottom margin: 0 
        range: (0, 100)
    top margin: 0 
        range: (0, 100)
    right margin: 0 
        range: (0, 100)
    left margin: 0 
        range: (0, 100)
    Colorspace: Default 
        supported: Default, SMPTE_170M_YCC, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, opRGB, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_RGB, BT2020_YCC, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, DCI-P3_RGB_Theater
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 32 
        supported: 32
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
  3840x2160 (0x48) 297.000MHz +HSync +VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  3840 start 4016 end 4104 total 4400 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  30.00Hz
  4096x2160 (0x49) 297.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  4096 start 4184 end 4272 total 4400 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  30.00Hz
  4096x2160 (0x4a) 297.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  4096 start 5064 end 5152 total 5280 skew    0 clock  56.25KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  25.00Hz
  4096x2160 (0x4b) 297.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  4096 start 5116 end 5204 total 5500 skew    0 clock  54.00KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  24.00Hz
  4096x2160 (0x4c) 296.703MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  4096 start 4184 end 4272 total 4400 skew    0 clock  67.43KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  29.97Hz
  4096x2160 (0x4d) 296.703MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  4096 start 5116 end 5204 total 5500 skew    0 clock  53.95KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  23.98Hz
  3840x2160 (0x4e) 297.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  3840 start 4896 end 4984 total 5280 skew    0 clock  56.25KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  25.00Hz
  3840x2160 (0x4f) 297.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  3840 start 5116 end 5204 total 5500 skew    0 clock  54.00KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  24.00Hz
  3840x2160 (0x50) 296.703MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  3840 start 4016 end 4104 total 4400 skew    0 clock  67.43KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  29.97Hz
  3840x2160 (0x51) 296.703MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  3840 start 5116 end 5204 total 5500 skew    0 clock  53.95KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  23.98Hz
  1920x1080 (0x52) 297.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock 135.00KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock 120.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x53) 297.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock 112.50KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock 100.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x54) 296.703MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock 134.87KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock 119.88Hz
  1920x1080 (0x55) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x56) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock  56.25KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  50.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x57) 148.352MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.43KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  59.94Hz
  1920x1080i (0x58) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  33.75KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
  1920x1080i (0x59) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
        h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock  28.12KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock  50.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x5a) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  33.75KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  30.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x5b) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock  28.12KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  25.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x5c) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2558 end 2602 total 2750 skew    0 clock  27.00KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  24.00Hz
  1920x1080i (0x5d) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  33.72KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock  59.94Hz
  1920x1080 (0x5e) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  33.72KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  29.97Hz
  1920x1080 (0x5f) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2558 end 2602 total 2750 skew    0 clock  26.97KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  23.98Hz
  1680x1050 (0x60) 119.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1728 end 1760 total 1840 skew    0 clock  64.67KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1080           clock  59.88Hz
  1600x900 (0x61) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1624 end 1704 total 1800 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
        v: height  900 start  901 end  904 total 1000           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x1024 (0x62) 135.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1296 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  79.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  75.02Hz
  1280x1024 (0x63) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1440x900 (0x64) 88.750MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1488 end 1520 total 1600 skew    0 clock  55.47KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  926           clock  59.90Hz
  1280x800 (0x65) 71.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock  49.31KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  823           clock  59.91Hz
  1152x864 (0x66) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1344 total 1600 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  900           clock  75.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x67) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  45.00KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x68) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1720 end 1760 total 1980 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  50.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x69) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  44.96KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  59.94Hz
  1024x768 (0x6a) 78.750MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1040 end 1136 total 1312 skew    0 clock  60.02KHz
        v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  800           clock  75.03Hz
  1024x768 (0x6b) 75.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1328 skew    0 clock  56.48KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  70.07Hz
  1024x768 (0x6c) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  832x624 (0x6d) 57.284MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   832 start  864 end  928 total 1152 skew    0 clock  49.73KHz
        v: height  624 start  625 end  628 total  667           clock  74.55Hz
  800x600 (0x6e) 50.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  856 end  976 total 1040 skew    0 clock  48.08KHz
        v: height  600 start  637 end  643 total  666           clock  72.19Hz
  800x600 (0x6f) 49.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  816 end  896 total 1056 skew    0 clock  46.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  625           clock  75.00Hz
  800x600 (0x70) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  720x576 (0x71) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  732 end  796 total  864 skew    0 clock  31.25KHz
        v: height  576 start  581 end  586 total  625           clock  50.00Hz
  720x576i (0x72) 13.500MHz -HSync -VSync Interlace
        h: width   720 start  732 end  795 total  864 skew    0 clock  15.62KHz
        v: height  576 start  580 end  586 total  625           clock  50.00Hz
  720x480 (0x73) 27.027MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  720x480 (0x74) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  720x480i (0x75) 13.514MHz -HSync -VSync Interlace
        h: width   720 start  739 end  801 total  858 skew    0 clock  15.75KHz
        v: height  480 start  488 end  494 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  720x480i (0x76) 13.500MHz -HSync -VSync Interlace
        h: width   720 start  739 end  801 total  858 skew    0 clock  15.73KHz
        v: height  480 start  488 end  494 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  640x480 (0x77) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  720 total  840 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  481 end  484 total  500           clock  75.00Hz
  640x480 (0x78) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  664 end  704 total  832 skew    0 clock  37.86KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  492 total  520           clock  72.81Hz
  640x480 (0x79) 30.240MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  704 end  768 total  864 skew    0 clock  35.00KHz
        v: height  480 start  483 end  486 total  525           clock  66.67Hz
  640x480 (0x7a) 25.200MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  640x480 (0x7b) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  720x400 (0x7c) 28.320MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  738 end  846 total  900 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  400 start  412 end  414 total  449           clock  70.08Hz
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x46
    Timestamp:  1704831
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      4
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    max bpc: 8 
        range: (8, 12)
    bottom margin: 0 
        range: (0, 100)
    top margin: 0 
        range: (0, 100)
    right margin: 0 
        range: (0, 100)
    left margin: 0 
        range: (0, 100)
    Colorspace: Default 
        supported: Default, SMPTE_170M_YCC, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, opRGB, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_RGB, BT2020_YCC, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, DCI-P3_RGB_Theater
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 41 
        supported: 41
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
```

In kernel log, when I search `hdmi`, here is some relevant output.

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep hdmi
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: coherent_pool=1M 8250.nr_uarts=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_compat_alsa=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_hdmi=1 video=HDMI-A-1:3840x2160M@30 smsc95xx.macaddr=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX vc_mem.mem_base=0x3ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x40000000  console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=XXXXXXXX-XX rootfstype=ext4 fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles
... non-relavent output is omitted
```

The boot configuration file (`/boot/config.txt`) is as the following. KMS driver is used.

```
$ cat /boot/config.txt 
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=18

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

# Automatically load overlays for detected cameras
camera_auto_detect=1

# Automatically load overlays for detected DSI displays
display_auto_detect=1

# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

# Run in 64-bit mode
arm_64bit=1

# Disable compensation for displays with overscan
disable_overscan=1

[cm4]
# Enable host mode on the 2711 built-in XHCI USB controller.
# This line should be removed if the legacy DWC2 controller is required
# (e.g. for USB device mode) or if USB support is not required.
otg_mode=1

[all]

[pi4]
# Run as fast as firmware / board allows
arm_boost=1

[all]

# enable 4k60hz hdmi output
hdmi_enable_4kp60=1
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would post on https://forums.raspberrypi.com

Comment: Please confirm that you use microHDMI-0. Only microHDMI-0 supports this mode. It is the one located closer to power supply of Pi 4.

Comment: @MatsK While I can't confirm it as I don't have microHDMI cable, the Argon case exposed 2 full size HDMI ports. I tried booting the Pi with either port connected, and I won't be able to set the frequency to 60Hz in the built in Screen Configuration tool of Pi. The Screen Configuration tool did recognize them as different port as it showed `HDMI-1` for the original port, and `HDMI-2` for the other port.